# Teaming the 2 ports of a hp 361T pcie Dual port GB Nic

Tags: redundancy, lacp, network-teaming, etherchannel

We have a network with two switches stacked for redundancy. We have a HO 36LT PCI-e Dual port NIC and an Intel x520 10GbE port adapter.

I want to be able to assign one IP address for both ports. I will one port to one switch, and the other port to the other switch, so that if one switch fails, I still have connectivity through the other switch.

How can I configure this? Is this something I set in the cards settings in the operating system, or somewhere else?

The operating system is Windows 7 professional

it needs to be lacp compatible

Comment: It entirely depends on your operating system. I suggest you start with telling us that.

Comment: @mark henderson the operating system is Windows 7 professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's different ways of doing this:

#### LACP / Etherchannel

If your switches are genuinely stacked (i.e. with a high bandwidth stacking infrastructure such as 10Gbps ethernet stacking, or a dedicated 20Gbps stacking cable, or something similar - not just tied together with a normal ethernet cable running between two distinct switches), and you can create a LAG group between different ports on both switches, you could do this with LACP or Etherchannel. This gives you the advantage of having *up to* 2Gbps of bandwidth for your two 1Gbps port (but not always, LACP/Etherchannel isn't a one-size-fits-all approach to increasing bandwidth). However you need to have a network stack that supports this: Namely proper managed switches, the switches need to be stacked properly (i.e. appear as a single management unit), and you need an operating system has drivers that support this for your network card.

#### Static failover

This works in pretty much any scenario and is totally unrelated to your choice of network card and switching stack, but it relies entirely on your operating system. Your operating system basiscally checks the link status (or whatever other configurations the OS supports for checking) and makes the first network card with an active link status as "online". If that link fails, it switches to the next avaliable network card that has an avaliable link status

### Operating system support

The implementation of this depends entirely on your operating system. For Windows Server 2012 R2, the OS makes this really, really easy and can be done at the server management level. For older versions of Windows Server, such as 2008 R2, you will need to configure this using your network cards specific drivers/tools.

For example, here is a Server 2012 R2 box that I'm building at the moment that has two NICs in static failover, and each link has a failed connection:

[image]

As another example, here is an ESXi static failover. Although these 4 adapters are configured as all active, in the event that a single port loses connectivity then there are still three others. This configuration is actually two quad-port NICs. Two ports from each NIC are in this vSwitch, one port from each card goes to one port on each switch so that we can sustain a switch failure or a NIC failure.

[image]

### Switch Support

To do LACP teaming you need switches that support this. These are usually called LAGs (Link Aggregation Groups), and you need matching LACP or Etherchannel configurations on your switch ports and on the network cards themselves.

Comment: @ Mark Henderson The switches are stacked so they are seen as one Unit and they are using lacp.(i have not set this up it was other more clever people :)) We are running with Windows 7 so i am now guessing that it's only with server software that I can make use of this... But you mentioned static failover, that sounds like the one I want. If one switch dies then the link will go dead and the os will switch to the other Ethernet port? Can they keep the same IP address? If you want I can start a new topic?

Comment: @DavyGravy your best bet is to get any HP Configuration utilities that there are and to do LACP. Static failover is usually a configuration of the OS, and Windows 7 does not do this.